# Is it possible to construct an assignment expression using rlang?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang

I'm trying to use the rlang package to construct an expression that does an assignment, given a right-hand side expression (the value to assign) and a left-hand side expression (the place to assign it to). For example, let's say I want to construct and evaluate the expression `a <- 5`:

```
> library(rlang)
> a <- "Not 5"
> lhs <- quo(a)
> rhs <- quo(5)
> eval_tidy(quo( (!!lhs) <- (!!rhs)) ) # Error
Error in (~a) <- (~5) : could not find function "(<-"
> eval_tidy(quo(`<-`(!!lhs, !!rhs))) # Error
Error in ~a <- ~5 : could not find function "~<-"
> eval_tidy(quo(`<-`(!!f_rhs(lhs), !!rhs))) # No error, but no effect
[1] 5
> stopifnot(a == 5)
Error: a == 5 is not TRUE
> print(a)
[1] "Not 5"
```

As you can see, none of the above methods of constructing and evaluating this assignment have the desired effect. Is there any way to do this correctly?

**Edit:** Using `assign` instead of `<-` is not a good solution, because it only works for variables, not elements of objects. For example, it won't work for:

```
> a <- list(ShouldBeFive="Not 5")
> lhs <- quo(a$ShouldBeFive)
```

**Edit 2:** I have written a [proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/aa8b9856036a8ff93b1656fc0548697b) that demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish. It defines an `assign_general` function that allows arbitrary left-hand sides, e.g. `assign_general(a[[1]], 5)` is equivalent to `a[[1]] <- 5`. However, my implementation seems kind of hackish, I don't know what corner cases I may have missed, and I'm still not sure if there's a more direct way to do it, so I'm still interested to see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: Can you just use `assign`?

Comment: `assign` won't work on arbitrary left-hand-sides. What if `lhs <- quo(a[[1]])`?

Comment: Can I ask why you're attached to using rlang?

Comment: rlang is the metaprogramming tool I'm most familiar with. If you have a good solution using something else, that's fine too.

Answer (score 3):

**1) rlang::lang** We can use `rlang::lang` like this:

```
library(rlang)

# inputs
a <- "Not 5"
lhs <- quote(a)
rhs <- 5

L <- lang("<-", lhs, rhs)
eval(L)
a
## [1] 5
```

**2) call** or without `rlang` use `call` in place of `lang`:

```
# inputs
a <- "Not 5"
lhs <- quote(a)
rhs <- 5
cc <- call("<-", lhs, rhs)

eval(cc)
a
## [1] 5
```

**2a)** Both of the above also work in the case that `lhs` is an appropriate expression.  For example using the built-in data frame `BOD`:

```
# inputs
BOD2 <- BOD
lhs <- quote(BOD2$xyz)
rhs <- 5

cc <- call("<-", lhs, rhs)
eval(cc)
names(BOD2)
## [1] "Time"   "demand" "xyz"
```

**2b) assign_general**

```
assign_general <- function(lhs, rhs, envir = parent.frame()) {
       cc <- call("<-", substitute(lhs), substitute(rhs))
       eval(cc, envir = envir)
}

# test
a <- 1:5
assign_general(a[3], 5)
a
## [1] 1 2 5 4 5
```

Some alternatives to the `call` statement would be:

```
cc <- substitute(call("<-", lhs, rhs))
```

or

```
cc <- substitute(lhs <- rhs)
```

**2c)** Of course this would be sufficient:

```
assign_general2 <- `<-`

a <- 1:5
assign_general2(a[3], 5)
## [1] 1 2 5 4 5
```

**3) rlang version of assign_general** An rlang implementation of `assign_general` in (2b) can be obtained by replacing `call` with `lang` and `substitute` with `enexpr`:

```
library(rlang)
assign_general3 <- function(lhs, rhs, envir = parent.frame()) {
       L <- lang("<-", enexpr(lhs), enexpr(rhs))
       eval(L, envir = envir)
}

# test
a <- 1:5
assign_general3(a[3], 5)
a
## [1] 1 2 5 4 5
```

**4) strings** Another possibility is to deparse the arguments into strings:

```
assign_general4 <- function(lhs, rhs, envir = parent.frame()) {
   s <- paste(deparse(substitute(lhs)), "<-", deparse(substitute(rhs)))
   p <- parse(text = s)
   eval(p, envir = envir)
}

# test
a <- 1:5
assign_general4(a[3], 5)
a
## [1] 1 2 5 4 5
```

Comment: `rlang::lang` is deprecated now, please use  `call2()` and `new_call()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of meta programming is using expressions as strings and being able to perform assignments to an L-value which can also be declared as a string.  The assign function is reusable in meta programming in some cases.

```
rhs <- "1 > 0"
assign("lhs", eval(eval_tidy(parse(text=rhs))))
lhs
[1] TRUE
```

Above you can see that both lhs and rhs are passed as strings and an expression is assigned to an L-value.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, `assign` is not sufficiently general. Unlike `<-`, it cannot assign to elements within a list, or other parts of objects. It can only assign to variable names in an environment.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of dark magic and some luck I was able to achieve what you are after:

```
library(rlang)

expr<-quote(x<-1) # just some sample assignment operator to modify
a <- list(ShouldBeFive="Not 5")
lhs <- quo(a[[1]])
rhs <- quo(5)

expr[[2]] <-UQE(eval(lhs))
expr[[3]] <-UQE(eval(rhs))
expr
>a[[1]] <- 5

eval(expr)
a$ShouldBeFive
>5
```

Here's hopefully cleaner alternative that does not depend on `rlang`:

```
b <- list(ShouldBeSix="Not 6")
lhs <- quote(b[[1]])
rhs <- quote(6)

eval(substitute(x <- value,list(x = lhs, value = eval(rhs))))
b$ShouldBeSix
```